# Is there a relation between $P^*|D|P$ and $|P^*DP|$?

Tags: matrices

Considering in the complex fields. Let $P$ be a nonsingular matrix, $P^* $ be its conjugate transpose, is there a relation between $P^*|D|P$ and $|P^*DP|$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix?  In particular, is it true

$P^* |D|P \ge |P^*DP|$ in the sense of Lowner order, or is there an order for eigenvalues?

Here $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$, the absolute value of a complex matrix.

**Edit** As I know from Suvrit's answer, there is no relation like $P^* |D|P \ge |P^* DP|$ in the sense of Lowner order. So my question becomes, is the $i$th largest eigenvalue of 
$P^* |D|P$ larger than that of $|P^*DP|$?

Comment: Even the modified question has a negative answer; please see my update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** In the edited question, the OP asks whether $\lambda_i^\downarrow(P^*|D|P) \ge \lambda_i^\downarrow(|P^*DP|)$ (or even the reverse direction). Such a relations do not hold either. Take for e.g., $P=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\\\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, and use the same $D$ as below.

Then, we have $\lambda^\downarrow(P^*|D|P) = (41.22, 0.776)$, while $\lambda^\downarrow(|P^*DP|) = (23.369, 1.369)$.

However, if one assume that $P$ is a contraction, then several interesting results can be shown.

---

I don't think there is any useful relation.

Here is a counterexample:

\begin{equation*}
  P =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2\\\\
    2 & 4
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
  D = \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 0\\\\
    0 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
  P^T|D|P =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    12 & 16\\\\
    16 & 24
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and

\begin{equation*}
    |P^TDP|^2 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
      640 & 1536\\\\
      1536 & 3712
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
  \lambda(P^T|D|P - |P^TDP|) = (-3.3678, 31.4856),
\end{equation*}
which is indefinite.

Comment: Isn't your $P^TDP=[8, 24; 
    24,    56]$, then $|P^TDP|=[11.3137,   22.6274;
   22.6274,   56.56858]$?

Comment: sorry, while typesetting I reran with 'sqrt' instead of 'sqrtm' by mistake; it's still a counterexample with the matrix squareroot--- thanks for catching.

Comment: I think there is a relation between eigenvalues, i.e. the $k$th largest eigenvlaue of $P^* |D|P$ is no less than the $k$th largest eigenvalue of $|P^*DP|

Comment: Sure, one can have several inequalities; All I am saying is that the semidefinite ordering that you asked in your second question above, does not hold in either direction because of the above indefinite matrix.

Comment: also note that the matrix $P$ that I am using is about as nice as it can get, because $P$ above is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not divide everything by 2?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: nope; no reason. was the first matrix that came to mind, and it turned out to give an counterexample. So I did not think beyond that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the same example above, I found

p=[1,1;1,2]

p =

```
 1     1
 1     2
```

> > d=[-1,0;0,2]

d =

```
-1     0
 0     2
```

> > c=[1,0;0,2]

c =

```
 1     0
 0     2
```

> > eig(((p*d*p)^2)^(1/2))

ans =

```
0.2426
8.2426
```

> > eig(p*c*p)

ans =

```
0.1690
```

11.8310

But this example shows it is possible the majorization relation holds.